# Google Search Console indexing pages from a different domain on the same server

Tags: google-search-console, search-engine-indexing

I have two domains (old-domain.com & new-domain.com) hosted on the same server (same IP). old-domain.com has tens of thousands of pages and is 20 years old, while new-domain.com only consists of a couple of pages all hosted in the root folder.

The Google Search Console is telling me that Google is indexing old-domain.com pages as if they also exist for new-domain.com.

How do I tell Google that certain pages only belong to a specific domain without using Sitemaps? (old-domain.com has too many pages for me to do this)

Comment: Are these pages displayed in Google SERP when searching with the directive  site:new-domain.com/& ?

Comment: Can you send a screenshot of Google Search Console showing this behavior?

Comment: @skill yes they can. Although they don't exist, so Google says "Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site." when you click on the link in the SERP

Comment: @MikeCiffone I find them by going to: Coverage -> Valid -> Indexed, not submitted in sitemap in the Google Search Console

Comment: there are currently too many reasons for this behavior. getting a screenshot with an example of such a page is a great idea. you can save the screenshot to a cloud like Google Drive and provide a public view link to keep your site anonymous

Comment: I'm not sure what I can screenshot, but here is an example. If you Google "arrival of the gods risolto bug sms" you will get this URL as the first result http://www.arrivalofthegods.com/news/iphone_risolto_bug_sms/63777.htm. This URL (from new-domain.com) does not exist, but all the indexed information is from old-domain.com. So this URL does exist with a different domain.

Comment: Here is the cache of this page from google.  http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:HML9g3SRo5sJ:www.arrivalofthegods.com/news/iphone_risolto_bug_sms/63777 Your content could have simply been copied.

Comment: @skill pc-facile.com is my other domain. The URL I indicated actually exists (and rightfully so) on pc-facile.com. How do I tell Google that hundreds of URLs like "/news/iphone_risolto_bug_sms/63777.htm" do not exist on arrivalofthegods.com?